# numpy.expand_dims: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples, typeerror

I am reading NumPy Docs for expand_dims in this link:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html

When I run this part:

```
x = np.array([1, 2])
y = np.expand_dims(x, axis=(0, 1))
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'
```

Comment: Giving a tuple for the `axis` was added in NumPy 1.18.  Which version are you using? You can check with `print(np.__version__)`

Comment: Numpy version: 1.16.6. Thanks, I will update it.